# Calculate the Average of Data frame iteratively

Tags: r

I have a set of Data and I want to be able to iteratively calculate the Average. i.e. the first two points, then the first three points, then first four points, and so on.

For example,

`D <- [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`

`Average <- [1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 3.5]`

Is there any way to do that in `R`?

Comment: `D <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6); Average = dplyr::cummean(D)` or if you want to start with average of first two `dplyr::cummean(D)[-1]` to drop the first element.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```r
D <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
(cumsum(D)/1:length(D))[-1]
# [1] 1.5 2.0 2.5 3.0 3.5
```